# when one can expect $\left \| |x|^{2}x- |y|^{2}y \right \| \leq \frac{1}{2} \left \| (x-y) \right \|$?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces

Suppose $(X, \left\|\cdot \right \|)$ is [Banach algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra) with the property that $\left\| (|x|^{2}x) \right\| \leq \left\|x\right \|^{3};$ for every $x\in X.$ Let $y_{0}\neq 0 \in X$ and fix it; and take $M= 2\left | y_{0} \right\|.$ We consider, closed ball of radius $M$ centred at the origin in the space $X$, that is, $B_{M}= \{x\in X: \left\|x\right \| \leq M \}.$

Let $x, y \in B_{M}.$

> **My Questions**:  (1)Can we expect $\left \| |x|^{2}x- |y|^{2}y \right \| \leq \frac{1}{2} \left \| (x-y) \right \|$ ? (2) Or atleast, can we expect $\left \| |x|^{2}x- |y|^{2}y \right \| \leq C \left \| (x-y) \right \|$, where $C$ is constant, ? (3) Or , we can produce counter examples ?

(I guess this identity will be useful; $\left(|x|^{2}x-|y|^{2}y= (x-y)|x|^{2}+y (|x|^{2}-|y|^{2})\right).$

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, in general you cannot expect this. Simply consider $(X,\|\cdot\|)=(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$, and set $x=0$. Then the inequality reads $$|y|^3 \leq \frac{1}{2} |y|.$$ Obviously, this is in general not true for $y>1/\sqrt{2}$.
2. Yes. The equality $$\begin{align*} \|x\|^2 x - \|y\|^2 y &= (x-y)\|x\|^2 + y (\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2) \\ &= (x-y)\|x\|^2 + y (\|x\|+\|y\|)(\|x\|-\|y\|) \end{align*}$$ implies $$\big\| \|x\|^2 x - \|y\|^2 y \big\| \leq M^2 \|x-y\| + 2M^2 \cdot \big|\|x|-\|y\| \big| \leq 3M^2 \|x-y\|$$ using that $\|x\| \leq M$, $\|y\| \leq M$ and $\big|\|x\|-\|y\| \big| \leq \|x-y\|$ by the inverse triangle inequality.